# How to use Firebase Phone Number Authentication on React-Native [re-Captcha]

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm kind a new on react-native and i have a question.

I want to use Firebase phone auth on my React-Native project but when i read firebase docs it says we must use re-captcha for getting number from user.

But i can't find to how to use re-captcha on react-native because on firebase docs it says we should use "window" parameter on codes.

Anyone know how to solve that or alternative ways for it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately phone Auth is not supported on React-Native yet.